# String with query parameters in generateStaticParams

Tags: next.js, query-string, app-router, next.js14, generatestaticparams

Could you please advise me, I have a following page.tsx which gets the data from the server and delivers it to the Component:

```
export async function generateStaticParams ({ params: { product } }: IParamsProps) {
    switch (product) {
        case 'first':
            return [
                { doc: `doc?name=${product}&version=1.4&language=de` },
                { doc: `doc?name=${product}&version=1.3&language=de` },

                { doc: `doc?name=${product}&version=1.4&language=en` },
                { doc: `doc?name=${product}&version=1.3&language=en` },
            ];

        case 'second':
            return [
                { doc: `doc?name=${product}&version=1.6&language=de` },
                { doc: `doc?name=${product}&version=1.6&language=en` },
            ];

        default:
            return [];
    };
};

async function getData ({ params }: IPageProps & IParamsProps) {
    const {
        doc,
        product,
    } = params;

    const res = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3000/${product}${doc.slice(3)}`,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            cache: 'no-store',
        }
    );
    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
}

const Page = async (props) => {
    const {
        params 
    } = props;

    const data = await getData({ params });

    return <Component data={data} />
}
```

**app directory**: [lang]/web/[product]/[doc]

**next.js version**: 14.0.2

After executing the *npm run build*, the **question mark** is replaced by **%3F**. So that instead of

*doc?name=product_name&version=1.4&language=de*

I got the following path:

*doc%3Fname=product_name&version=1.4&language=de*.

How can this be fixed? **And is it even normal practice to generate query strings as static paths**?

Comment: This is no valid Next.js page component. Even it it would run, how could your site request `http://localhost:3000` during build? Rethink and re-code your page component. Before you do that. Start here: https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app

Comment: What you called "invalid Next.js-page" was taken from the documentation itself: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#static-site-generation-getstaticprops

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by “taken”. Possibly you took some ideas from the docs you linked and did something by your own. Right? I admit that I did not and will not analyze your code. Your code is missing a default export (or I don't see it) and you mix Page Router with App Router. You linked into the chapter “Step 6: Migrating Data Fetching Methods”. It explains how to migrate `getStaticProps` to App Router. It's your decision. Rethink and reformulate your question is my recommendation. I am writing this with good, constructive intent.

Comment: I apologize, you are right, the code did need to be reworked, I should have used the catch-all segment instead of the hacky solution with string parameters, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, and keep in mind. App Router and Page Router are different. They can coexist, but things work different. App Routes does not use `getStaticProps`. Good luck.